# Linear-gradient not covering entire background image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, linear-gradients

For some reason some of the rows aren't covered at the bottom by the linear-gradient, resulting in a nasty looking bright line at the bottom of some cards. The strangest part is that it doesn't occur on every card.

I've tested it in other browser as well.

```html
<a href="/artists">
  <div class="card">

  </div>
</a>


<style>
  .card {
    /* Set banner as card background */
    background-image: 
      linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 80%)),
      url(https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/060/211/960/large/citemer-liu-shenhexiao.jpg);
    /* Make banner fill card */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Set card aspect ratio */
    aspect-ratio: 3.5/ 1;
    /* Set card size */
    width: 600px;
    /* Center cropped banner*/
    background-position: center;
    /* Round card corners */
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* Add shadow behind card */
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--color-card-banner-shadow);*/
  }
  .card:hover {
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--color-card-banner-shadow-hover); */
  }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is directly to do with the linear gradient not being large enough, but a sort of edge effect one can get when the system is mapping CSS pixels to screen pixels. Does the white line change at all if you zoom in and out?

Comment: Yes it changes with zoom, how do you suggest me to fix this issue?

Comment: I’ve got round this sometimes by putting the background on a slightly larger element (possibly a pseudo element).

Comment: Or would there maybe be some way to extend this gradient outwards into nothingness and then the white spot would be engulfed, if you ever found 
 or find posts to this issue please let me know. I assume the root of this issue is something deeper in css than simply linear-gradients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is hacky and quite simple, add this to the css.

```css
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Fixes white line bug */
```

I hope this bug get's fixed at some point.